# Is it possible to use a GArray as a value in a GHashTable?

Tags: c, hashtable, glib

I'm trying to map strings to [GArrays](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Arrays.html) using a [GHashTable](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html). So far, I have not been successful.

I declare the hashtable like so:

```
hash_table = g_hash_table_new_full(g_str_hash, g_str_equal, g_free, NULL);
```

And my GArray like so:

```
array = g_array_new(1, 1, sizeof(uint64_t));
```

I'm trying to insert the array into the hashtable. Upon inserting it, I check to see if it's there. The key appears to be there, but the value it hashes to is `NULL`.

```
GArray *old_array;

g_hash_table_insert(hash_table,
           (gpointer) g_strdup(path),
           (gpointer) array);

if (g_hash_table_lookup_extended(hash_table,
            path, NULL, (void **) old_array)) {
    printf("stored value is %p\n", old_array);
}
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible? If so, how do I avoid the `NULL` value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rookie mistake. Needed to pass in `&old_array`.

```
GArray *old_array;

g_hash_table_insert(hash_table,
           (gpointer) g_strdup(path),
           (gpointer) array);

if (g_hash_table_lookup_extended(hash_table,
            path, NULL, (void **) &old_array)) {
    printf("stored value is %p\n", old_array);
}
```